# Call Unmanaged Code from SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, ssis, etl

I have Business Intelligence -> Integration Services Project where I have SSIS Packages -> Script Task. I need to call from Script Task Unmanaged code using DllImport. Since I don't know where code for Script Task is stored during run-time I can't call my unmanaged dll.

Example code below for Script Task:

```
using System; // Console
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // DllImport

class App
{
    [DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static int next(int n);

    static void Main()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(next(0));
       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

You can find more about Script Task [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345171(v=sql.120).aspx)

**Question:** How to call Unmanaged Code from SSRS Package -> Script Task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to copy c/c++ dll into "*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn*" which will be loaded when managed code calls **DllImport**

NOTE: 120 is version specific make sure to copy to the correct version that you have.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS won't load dll's by location, even managed dll's. You have to GAC them, http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html . I would therefore expect you to have to COM register your unmanaged dll, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx .

Comment: I am getting following error: The module ""%1"" was loaded but the entry-point %2 was not found.\n\nMake sure that ""%1"" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again
BTW: I am trying to use http://www.cryptopp.com/ dll

Comment: ok, so it's not a valid COM object either, so you would have to load it dynamically from location. sorry, I have a feeling that you're not going to find a direct solution for this. I think you probably need to write a strong named GAC'd .Net dll to act as an adapter, to dynamically load the dll from location. I don't know how you can easily search online for a solution. SSIS packages generally run from System32 from what I remember as their default working directory.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a good reason to be calling this library for encryption as opposed to using builtin .Net libraries?

Comment: Correct we have old project that uses this library to encrypt some data. So to de-crypt it we need to use same dll.